# Parse text file

Tags: java

I have an input text file in this format:

**JAN  Year     FEB  Year     MAR  Year     APR  Year     MAY   Year**

9.0  1916     9.8  1998    12.1  2012     16.9  1992    15.7   2011
  8.7  2007     8.9  2008    11.9  1938     15.2  2007    16.8   2008
  9.0  1916     9.8  1998    12.1  2012     16.9  1992    15.7   2011
  8.7  2007     8.9  2008    11.9  1938     15.2  2007    16.8   2008
  9.0  1916     9.8  1998    12.1  2012     16.9  1992    15.7   2011
  8.7  2007     8.9  2008    11.9  1938     15.2  2007    16.8   2008

How can i parse above file?
how can i get values of Month and year from above file in column wise fashion ?

I want to store value of each month for given year...

Help me...

Comment: SO is not a code writing service! Or an algorithm providing service!

Comment: What did you try? I suggest you can think about using .csv format with space delimited. Then map it to Java beans, like this post suggestion: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-csv-file/

Answer (score 1):

First split the string with `string.split()` which returns an array of words in the string separated by the delimiter (default is white space) .
Then, while looping over the new array of strings keep in mind that :
 all odd-numbered indices are the month.day, so split that by `string.split('.')`
 All even-numbered indices are year.

Happy parsing

Answer (score 1):

you can use Perl or TCL ,its easier to make parser of text file in these scripting languages

perl has got modules for different things , but for above file you just need to learn " regular expressions "